# Redirect to 127.0.0.1 when access a wordpress hosted with apache and nginx in proxy

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I have a wordpress hosted on Apache2 with Nginx in front of.
`<WORLD> ===> <NGINX PROXY> --> APACHE/DOCKER/STATIC WEBSITE etc...`

My nginx conf for wordpress proxy is :

```
server {
    server_name dev-www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:13400;
    }
}
```

My apache configuration :

```
Listen 13400

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:13400>
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/sites/dev-www/access_log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/sites/dev-www/error_log

        DirectoryIndex index.php

        DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/example.com/dev-www

        RewriteEngine On

        <Directory /var/www/sites/example.com/dev-www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And wordpress `.htaccess` :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The issue is when I go on  `dev-www.example.com/foobar.php` I am redirected to `127.0.0.1/foobar.php`. I know it's from `nginx` configuration `127.0.0.1` pop out put how to fix it ?

I try to proxy pass to `dev-www.example.com:13400` but I got an infinite loop :

> [Tue May 10 23:44:45.001680 2016] [core:error] [pid 1096] [client
>   127.0.0.1:54887] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use
>   'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use
>   'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer:
>   http://dev-www.example.com/

note: there is no problem with `http://dev-www.example.com` or `http://dev-www.example.com/index.php`
Thanks.

note2 : If I change nginx configuration to localhost:13400, then i'm redirected to localhost/login-3. It looks like .htaccess redirect to ServName and it is 127.0.0.1

Comment: "when I go on dev-www.example.com/foobar.php I am redirected" means when you enter this URL directly into the browser's location bar?

Comment: Yes, or click on link, same behavior. http://dev-www.example.com/login-3 redirect me to http://127.0.0.1/login-3

Comment: If I change nginx configuration to `localhost:13400`, then i'm redirected to `localhost/login-3`. It looks like `.htaccess` redirect to ServName and it is `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Have you tried `curl -D - dev-www.example.com` on the command line?

Comment: `curl -D - dev-www.example.com` works. `curl -D - dev-www.example.com/fooboar.php` fail (redirect to `127.0.0.1/foobar.php`). I thinks `.htaccess` redirect to wrong hostname.

Comment: There's no redirect in your `.htaccess`. Wordpress must be doing that.

Comment: What does curl output on failure?

Comment: It was a 404 error from `127.0.0.1/foobar.php`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's wordpress redirect to `HTTP_HOST`, adding

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
```

in `wp-config.php` fix it.

Comment: Thanks! My final solution to leave Wordpress config file unchanged was to add `ProxyPreserveHost On` to the proxy instance (on apache).

Comment: For nginx you have to add `proxy_set_header Host domain.com`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as you had exported your wordpress site from a local development system to productive system. Very likely you can not get into /wp-admin anymore as well. In this case you have to manually update the database entries in the table `wp_options`. Look for the options `siteurl` and `home`.

---

Please also try out to add this to wp-config.php (but i'm afraid, this is only targeted to outgoing requests)

```
define('WP_PROXY_HOST', '1.2.3.4');
define('WP_PROXY_PORT', '13400');
# define('WP_PROXY_USERNAME', 'my_user_name');
# define('WP_PROXY_PASSWORD', 'my_password');
define('WP_PROXY_BYPASS_HOSTS', 'localhost, www.example.com');
```

Comment: I already change it. Nothing change (but I can access to http://dev-www.example.com/ or /index.php) without any issue.

Comment: @CyrilALFARO What are those options set to?

Comment: there was an error on my post at apache conf, I fill IP and not URL, I just update my post.

Answer (score 1):

For Nginx, you have to make sure Host header is set correctly, your example should be:

```
server {
    server_name dev-www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host dev-www.example.com;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:13400;
    }
}
```