# Wordpress with Nginx proxy pass not loading resources

Tags: wordpress, nginx, server

I just migrate from blog.example.com to www.example.com/blog and just adding this configuration on my nginx:

```
location ~ /blog(/.*) {
 proxy_pass http://public-ip; #server IP where the wordpress installed
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

and then I change the wordpress setting for WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) from blog.example.com to www.example.com/blog

When I check the www.example.com/blog, the post list, post view and pagination works well. But the resources (css, js & images) not loaded at all.

Please note my nginx server used for load balancer for my web app (www.example.com) and the wordpress app (blog) in another server.

Am I missing something on the nginx configuration or maybe in the wordpress setting?

thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37149842/redirect-to-127-0-0-1-when-access-a-wordpress-hosted-with-apache-and-nginx-in-pr?noredirect=1#comment61852655_37149842

Comment: thanks for the reference. It's a bit different case. But I tried the answer and still no luck :)

Comment: It is probably the configuration of the blog server. All of a sudden you are looking for css and img under `/blog`. It is finding the WP index.php as that is the default to make pretty URLs work.